# Python using Excel Data for JSON Curl

Tags: python, excel, loops, curl

Hello Im running a CURL script against an API.  Im trying to have an excel sheet with all the needed information and use python to retrieve the dataframe, set the json data correctly for each row for a few hundred times, request the information, and append each row to an excel output sheet.  Sorry the initial code is bad, but it does retrieve all the information I want correctly and push it to an excel sheet on an individual request.

Data Structure from Excel

```
  ReceiptID  FirstName purchaseDate  LastName   Total  
1          1     Skip1   09-26-2022      XYZ   332.59          
2          2     Skip2   12-31-2021      ABC   124.88           
N          N      N        N              N     N
```

```
`Main part of the Code: 
json_data = {
    'FirstName': 'Skip',
    'LastName': 'XYZ'
    'purchaseDate': "08-12-2021",
    'total': '332.59',
    
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, json=json_data)
data = response.json()
for key in (data['receipts'][0]['Names'][0:]):
   FirstName = (key['FirstName'])
   LastName=(key['LastName'])
   purchaseDate=(key['purchaseDate'])
   total=(key['total'])
   a.append(FirstName)
   b.append(LastName)
   c.append(purchaseDate)
   d.append(total)

data= pd.DataFrame([a,b,c,d])
data= data.transpose()
data=(data.head(1000))
data.to_csv('TestingJson.csv')
```

What Ive been attempting and failing at:

```
path=r'filepath'
excel = pd.read_excel(path)

ReceiptID=[]
FirstName=[]
LastName=[]
purchaseDate=[]
Total=[]


for items in data:
   FirstName=data.FirstName
   LastName=data.LastName
   purchaseDate=data.purchaseDate
   Total=data.Total
   

container={}

x=0

while x< len(ReceiptID):
    container[ReceiptID[x]]=[
        FirstName[x],
        purchaseDate[x],
        LastName[x],
        Total[x],
        
    ]

    x=x+1
```

Written above in the original post

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The data structure is from excel and contains data on each row that is the necessary JSON data.  Im hoping to have python read the excel file, insert the JSON data into the code for each loop (row of data).  There are 100+ rows in the excel sheet. 

Im not sure how to get python to read the excel sheet, put the row data into the JSON data of the script, run through the Curl for each row in the excel file. Basicall execute the code using row 1 data, append to excel, execute the code with row 2 data, append, until the nth row is completed